# Get-ChildItem: Same subfolder in different parents folders

Tags: powershell

If have the following structure:

```
F:\ParentA\FindMe
F:\ParentA\DoNotFindMe
F:\ParentB\FindMe
F:\ParentB\SomethingElse
```

So in every parent folder (lots of them) i have subfolders and there is **exactly one** of those subfolders *with the same name every time* i want to find.

I thought about `$children = Get-ChildItem "F:\*\FindMe"` but this **only** returns the first *(in the top case **parentA**)* but as i said i need every parent folder.

Looping through is an alternative, but I was looking for a sleek/quick solution..

Comment: use -recurse in the drive F:, then iterate it and check if it matches with FindMe . Thats it

Comment: Are all parent folders on the same level of hierarchy, or do you have e.g. `F:\ParentA\FindMe` and `F:\something\ParentB\FindMe`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers They are all on the same level. That's why i hoped for a quick/small solution and not looping through.

Comment: Then `Get-ChildItem F:\*\FindMe` should give you a list with `F:\ParentA\FindMe` and `F:\ParentB\FindMe`. Add `-Force` if you have hidden folders.

Comment: The -force for hidden folders was the key ... didn't see thatt they were partially hidden >.> sorry